# Sharing mouse and keyboard input on virtual machines

Tags: virtualbox, sharing, input

So what I am trying to do is setup two or more virtual boxes (with lubuntu if posibble), and share my cursor and keyboard input for all virtual boxes. Is this possible? What software should I use?

Comment: You can do this with kvm and virtualbox, take you pick

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question, or maybe you haven't tried it yet.  But I have it working.

I have two computers, Lubuntu and Windows and each one has two virtual machines, one Win7 and one Lubuntu.

I installed Virtualbox in both computers and added the guest additions.  With both VMs running, my mouse moves from one to the other as though I am operating in the base system.  (I am currently on my Win10 machine and just discovered I did have both VMs running)

I did this once in the Lubuntu computer, but it froze up because the two together use all my system resources, but it worked until it crashed.

In the past, I remember that after installing Vbox, I would have to load the guest additions before I could sue the mouse and keyboard across the real OS and the virtual OS.  But now, it seems to default to sharing them at the install.